# How do I call a delete function inside another function without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am currently working on a program where a user can select number of parts based on the requirements and showing it in table form, also allowing them to delete the item they have selected without refreshing the page.
my view page is :

```
 <div class="col-md-6">    <h4>Estimate</h4>
                  <div  id="estimate">

              </div>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> + Add Part/Service</button>
                  </div>

                </div>  
                <div class="form-actions">

                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-cons" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Save</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-white btn-cons" type="button">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am showing the result on div id estimate.

My controller function code is :

```
      function estimate(){
$this->load->library('session');
$this->load->module('site_security');
$this->site_security->_make_sure_is_user();

if (!empty($this->input->post())) {
    $output = " ";

        $estimate_code = $this->input->post('estimate_code');
        $part_name = $this->input->post('part_name');
        $part_code = $this->input->post('part_code');
        $customer_price_with_gst = $this->input->post('customer_price_with_gst');
        $part_group_name = $this->input->post('part_group_name');
        $bname = $this->input->post('bname');


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `estimate`(`id`, `estimate_code`, `part_name`,`part_code`,`amt`,`part_group_name`,`brand`) VALUES
        ('','$estimate_code','$part_name','$part_code','$customer_price_with_gst','$part_group_name','$bname')";
        if ($this->_custom_query($sql)) {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM estimate where estimate_code ='$estimate_code'";
            $result = $this->_custom_query($query);

            $output .='  <table class="table table-hover no-more-tables">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>S.No</th>
                            <th>Part Code</th>
                            <th>Part Description</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>

                          </tr>';
                         $s = 1; $amt1 = "";
                          foreach ($result->result() as $row) {
                            $brand= $row->brand;

                            $s1[] =  $row->part_group_name;
                            $id = $row->id;
                            $amt = $row->amt;
                             $amt1 = $amt1+$amt;
                            $output .= '<tr>
                            <th>'.$s++.'</th>
                            <th>'.$row->part_code.'</th>
                            <th>'.$row->part_name.'</th>
                            <th>'. $amt.'</th>
                            <th>
                                 <form class="estimatedel" name="estimatedel">
                                  <input name="id" value="'.$id.'" type="hidden">
                                    <button type="button" id="estimatedel" value="estimatedel" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"onclick="return ajaxFunction();"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></form>

                                    </th>
                          </tr>';

                         } $counter = 0;
                     $sam = $s1;
                  $Query = "select max(total) as h from service_charge ";
                 if(count($sam) > 0)
               $Query .= " where ( ";
               foreach($sam as $Filtervalues)
                 {
                $counter++;
              $Query .= "part_group_name = '$Filtervalues'";
             if($counter != count($sam))
             $Query .= " or ";
              else
              $Query .= ")";
                }
             $result = $this->_custom_query($Query);
              foreach ($result->result() as $row1) {
$tot1=0;
$tot=$row1->h;

     }
          $total_amt = $tot+$amt1;

                          $output .=' <input type="hidden" name="estimate_code" value="'.$estimate_code.'">
                          <input type="hidden" name="estimate_amt" value="'.$amt1.'">
                          ';

        }
            echo $output;

            print_r('<input type="hidden" name="service_amt" value="'.$tot.'">
                <input type="hidden" name="total_amt" value="'.$total_amt.'">



                <tr><td colspan="3">Amount: </td><td style= "text-align:left;" colspan="2">'.$amt1.'</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">Service Charge: </td><td style= "text-align:left;" colspan="2">'.$tot.' </td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">Total Amount: </td><td style= "text-align:left;" colspan="2">'.$total_amt.' </td></tr>  </thead> </table>');
        }

     }
```

I am stuck on the delete part where user can delete any of the selected part without refreshing or losing the selected parts.

Answer (score 0):

Create jQuery function which trigger on checkbox change event, and check whether checkbox is checked or not. If checkbox is unchecked then and then only make a call to remove part from your list. may be below code will help you.

```
if($(this). prop("checked") == false){
  var checkboxid = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
      method:post,
      url: "remove_part.php", 
      data:{
       chkid:checkboxid
      }
      success: function(result){
          alert('removed successfully');
      }
  });
}
```